Use a different maven repository per build in gradle
I have a spring/gradle/kotlin backend Application, that I have to build in 2 networks. One has internet, the other does not, but it has a private maven repository.
Example part of build.gradle.kts:
...
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven (url = "https://artifactory.my.private.url/artifactory/maven-group/")
    }
...

This works fine when it has an internet connection.
Build fails when it only has an intranet connection, because it first tries the local mirror (may not exist) and then the internet one, and then it times out and fails the build. It never even tries the private repository. Only a 404 would make it skip to the next one, but in this case, it times out.
If I change the order, then it will fail when it only has an internet connection.
Is there a way to do this? I don't want to have to maintain 2 build.gradle.kts files and replace them inside the CI/CD system in build time.
Edit:
Solution:
repositories {
    if (properties.containsKey("isProd")) {
        println("using prod maven url")
        maven (url = "https://artifactory.my.private.url/artifactory/maven-group/")
    } else {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

To build:
./gradlew clean bootjar -P isProd=true


Is it an option to run the gradle build with different build properties? If so, you could just use a property 'intranet' and wrap the repo declarations in if-statements where one of the 2 repos is used depending on the existence of that property.

yep, it worked. thanks!

I think the idiomatic solution to this problem is using some custom init-script in environment where you need to adjust build's repositories.
I place the following custom-repositories.init.gradle.kts into $(GRADLE_USER_HOME)/init.d/ on CI nodes:
val mirrorBase = "https://artifactory.my.private.url"
val mavenCentralMirrorUrl = uri("$mirrorBase/MavenCentral-mirror/maven/v1")
val gradlePLuginsMirrorUrl = uri("$mirrorBase/GradlePlugins-mirror/maven/v1")

settingsEvaluated {
    pluginManagement {
        repositories {
            maven {
                url = gradlePLuginsMirrorUrl
            }
        }
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url = mavenCentralMirrorUrl
        }
    }
}

This will implicitly affect any Gradle project built by this CI node.
If your build is divided into multiple Gradle projects or if you use "included builds", which has some non-typical repositories {}-block, then you can use if (project/rootProject.name == "xxx") clauses in a repositories {}-block for a more fine-grained control over substitution of repositories.
